# ComposableSearchablePushRow with Eureka and Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8, uisearchbar, eureka-forms

I'm facing a problem using ComposableSearchablePushRow to extend the existing Eureka plug-in for Swift 3. Source code of this extension can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/bithavoc/f5c9d06f024bfb5d9d3bd9452b94849f

My Problem is that I don't really know how to correctly call the ComposableSearchablePushRow() in my FormViewController.

This is what I've tried before:

```
+++ ComposableSearchablePushRow<String>("Test") {

}
```

Thrown error is like:

"Extra argument in call"

Answer (score 0):

I had been researching and working in your questions, and this are my results, well first of all you can’t use `String` as generic type for the row `ComposableSearchablePushRow` because you need that your generic type implement the `SearchableItem` protocol so, in my modest opinion this cell can fit your needs,  but you can always implement this protocol in your data type, example in my case I use a class called `ExampleQuestion` but even when I had implemented the protocol  I can´t make this works, because of this enum `ComposableSearchableItem` your dataProvider must return an array of `ComposableSearchableItems<YourClassType>` in my case `ComposableSearchableItems<ExampleQuestion>` and I can´t find a way for this to work because `ComposableSearchableItems` is an `enum`.

this is the code

```
        <<< ComposableSearchablePushRow<ExampleQuestion>.init(tag: "Test").cellSetup({ (pushCell, row) in
            row.dataProvider = self.provider2
        })
```

Maybe this ComposableSearchablePushRow is not complete or maybe not tested, I hope this helps in some way, if you have some advances in this topics please let me know, Best Regards

Comment: One step forward: Now I'm able to call like +++ ComposableSearchablePushRow<ExampleStruct>("test"){ $0.title="test title"; ... } But when I try to set options of struct ExampleStruct (even with downcast), I get the error "ComposableSearchableItem<ExampleStruct> is not a subtype of ExampleStruct"

Comment: @calli23 its the same problem i am facing, the problem is ComposableSearchableItem enum, but in this cell github page the author don't have some example of how use it, so maybe its better ask for example there